# Copy table rows to another table html

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, rows

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZuH7/)

I have a table where if I click on a given row that row will be copied  to another table and the rows above will be hidden. So for example  if I click the 126th row it will hide  rows 0 through 125. However it is not copying that target row to the other table. What's going wrong?

```
var Startcheck = true; 
function SelectStartPoint(dataSet)
{

    if (Startcheck)
        var $test = $(dataSet).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join("-");

    var data = $test.split('-');


    $("tr:lt(" + data[0] + ")").css("display", "none");
        var items = [];
        var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        var newButtonHTML = 
        "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='Edit()' /><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";

        $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function(e) {});

        $(newTr).children("td:last").html("").html(newButtonHTML);
        items.push(newTr);
        newTr.appendTo($("#stopsTable"));
}
```

Comment: GetHoverInfo() and GetHoverMarker() functions are not defined!!

Comment: in your demo when SelectStartPoint is called?

Comment: Bind click event for the button `$('.addBtn').click(function(){
    SelectStartPoint($(this).parent().parent());
});`

Comment: it will remove all the up rows from selected and it will also copy selected row to another table

Comment: [how's this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8ZuH7/1/) (please note I had to remove click functions from your table)

Comment: bt it not create which is i want 

like Edit and delete
var newButtonHTML = 
        "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='Edit()' /><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";

        $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function(e) {});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your desired effect using the following jQuery:

```
var rows = $('#myTable tbody tr'),
    copyTable = $('#stopsTable tbody');

rows.click(function() {
    var row = $(this),
        cloneRow = row.clone(),
        thisIndex = rows.index(row);

    copyTable.append(cloneRow);

    rows.filter(function() {
        return rows.index($(this)) < thisIndex;
    }).hide();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8ZuH7/1/)

[Example with use of Phil's prevAll](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8ZuH7/2/)

**EDIT**

As per your comments with added edit and delete buttons:

```
var rows = $('#myTable tbody tr'),
    copyTable = $('#stopsTable tbody');

rows.click(function() {
    var row = $(this),
        cloneRow = row.clone();

    cloneRow.children('td:last-child').html('<input type="submit" value="Edit" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" class="edit"><input type="submit" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100px;" class="delete">');

    copyTable.append(cloneRow);

    row.prevAll().hide();
});

copyTable.on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('do edit function here');
});

copyTable.on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8ZuH7/5/)

Comment: I have only problem about this code 
i want button new row which is copy to another table 
the button are 


var newButtonHTML = 
        "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='Edit()' /><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";

        $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function(e) {});

Comment: NO i want remove select as stop .. it replace with Edit and Delete button

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to tell how your code above relates to your problem.

If I look at your jsFiddle example, I can simplify the tasks quite a lot.

First I want to cache the table itself. Then I'll bind a click event handler to the button elements in your table (I'm assuming these are static and do not have additional rows being added to the source table via Ajax or something):

```
var table = $('#myTable');

$('input', table).click(function(e){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().remove(); // remove all previous rows

    console.info(row.html());
});
```

You can see in this example that we're getting the row from which the button was clicked, cloning it and then removing all the previous rows above.

If you want to remove the row containing the clicked button as well as its predecessors, you'd use the following line:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll().andSelf().remove();
```

I can now append that target row as follows:

```
$('myTargetTable tbody').append(row);
```

Does this solve your problem or is there more that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is [my solution](http://jsbin.com/bazax/4/edit):

```
$(function(){
  $('#myTable .addBtn').click(function(){ 
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    $('#stopsTable tbody').append(tr.clone());
    tr.prevAll().hide();
  });
});
```